# Impartial or generic word for both stretch/dilate and squeeze/compress

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a word that refers to squeezing/compression or stretching/dilation while being impartial to the "direction"? For example, `shift` does not denote which direction is being moved in.

- `Malleate` doesn't quite work and is quite obscure, given by Merriam-Webster as "to beat or mark or dent (a metal) with a hammer in working or decorating". It also has no synonyms given anywhere I can find.
- `Transform` is how it is referred to in mathematical settings but doesn't work for other situations.
- `Adapt` or `alter` are not specific enough in what is happening to the object
- **Edit:** `Scale` or `resize` do not work as they imply that only the size of the object changes and not its shape

Sentence examples:

- The object was __ by the atmospheric pressure
- Please __ the square peg to make it fit in the round hole

(The object could have been made smaller or larger in either scenario.)

Answer (score 1):

How about [**deform**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/deform):

> Distort the shape or form of; make misshapen.

Another possibility, suggested by the above, is [**distort**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/distort):

> Pull or twist out of shape.

Answer (score 0):

***resize*** means exactly this.

> vt To change the size of something
>
> The most basic tools in image editing software are crop, resize, and rotate.

Googling *resize definition* will gwt you a dozen or more online dictionary entries for this word.

Comment: Good thought, I was thinking additionally about the shape (otherwise `scale` would work perfectly aswell) but I can see my question does not state that specifically

Answer (score 0):

“(un)squeeze” or “(un)stretch” would do. It is idiomatic English, if not formal.

Comment: Could you provide some references?